# Apache ProxyPass fallback when no other matches

Tags: apache, virtualhost, mod-proxy, proxypass

I have the following proxypass directives in a virtualhost:

```
ProxyPass /mail http://127.0.0.1:8080/ #webmail app
ProxyPass /mail/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8082/  #Myapp
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8082/
```

But on http://my.domain.com/mail y alway get "Myapp" as response.

I want to use "Myapp" as default when no other ProxyPass patterns matches and (i.e.) webmail app when the proper url is entered. Is it possible?

I've already tried switching directives order with same results.